# Sum of the numpy array in a sliding window without loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple array with size **(n, )** and I want to build another array with that **without using a loop.** I want to sum the values in a window of size **4**. For example, in the following array, sum of the first 4 values (4, 0, 2, 1) is 7, sum of the second 4 values is 2, and sum of the third four values is 8. Can you help me with that? Thanks

```
import numpy as np
A= np.random.randint(5, size = (12,))
#A array([4, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2])
out: array([7, 2,8])
```

Comment: You cannot do it without a loop.  End of story.  The loop might be part of a generator or a comprehension, but there will be a loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'd guess the author is looking for a solution without an _explicit_ loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an easy sum - make a 2d array and add across columns:

```
In [173]: x=np.array([4, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2])

In [174]: x
Out[174]: array([4, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2])

In [175]: x.reshape(-1,4)
Out[175]: 
array([[4, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 4, 2]])

In [176]: x.reshape(-1,4).sum(axis=1)
Out[176]: array([7, 2, 8])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can take a striding subset of the cumulative sum and subtract the first sums from the second and subsequent:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([4, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2])

R = A.cumsum()[3::4]
R[1:] -= R[:-1]

print(R) # [7 2 8]
```